# What's the difference between “notre” and “nos”?

Tags: pronoms, adjectifs, possessif

I'm using duolingo to practice my French which is good for immersion but kind of lacking on grammatical explanations. I keep running across what looks like two types of possessive pronouns. Sometimes it uses *notre* or *votre*, etc. and other times it's *nos* or *vos*, etc. What's the difference between the two sets and when do I use each?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*Notre* and *votre*, like *mon/ma*, *ton/ta*, *son/sa* and *leur* are singular forms of the possessive adjectives:

> Notre maison, votre liberté.

*Nos* and *vos* are plural, like *mes*, *tes*, *ses*, *leurs*.

> Nos pieds, vos souhaits.

Additionally, *le(s) nôtre(s)*, and *le(s) vôtre(s)* are the corresponding pronouns. Like *le(s) mien(s)*, *le(s) tien(s)*, *le(s) sien(s)*, *le(s) leur(s)*.